# How to filter category wise product in Django using generic class view

Tags: django, class, generics, product, categories

I am making a POS system where there would be customers and each customer would have there own transactions. I can show all the transactions but having tough time figuring out how to filter transactions based on customer only.
In models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class AccountHolder(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, auto_created=True)
    share_deposit = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    share_return = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    share_total = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to use generic classes in order do the filtration.
Inside views.py

```
class CustomerDetail(ListView):
    model = AccountHolder
    context_object_name = 'customers'
    template_name = 'customertransaction.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['customers'] = context['customers'].filter(customer=self.request.customer)
```

Answer (score 0):

*If you want to filter the result of a generic class based view,* **override get_queryset() method** instead of manipulate `context_data` variable.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    customer_id = self.kwargs['id']  # Assume that the url is like /account_holder/5 where 5 is the id of the customer
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=customer_id)
    return AccountHolder.objects.filter(customer=customer)
```

*But if for somme reason, you are forced to use context_data*, then correct your filter like this :

```
# You wrote customer=self.request.customer
# If you have not wrote any middleware, request have not attribut customer
# You must retrieve the customer and filter AccountHolder by it.
customer = Customer.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])
context['customers'] = context['customers'].filter(customer=cutomer)
```